# How do I detect an available array slot in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, math

This is an odd question because I don't know what to call it! I have an array with a list of numbers. These numbers are automatically detected, so I can't set them.

The numbers come in ranges like "**001, 002, 003, 004, 005, 006**" or "**001, 003, 004**".
*Note that in the first list of numbers, they all go up (1,2,3,4,5,6) but in the second one they are less ordered (1, 3, 4).*

My complicated question is this: How do I detect the first available array entry? For the first one, I would want "**007**" and for the second one "**002**". How on earth do I detect this and add an array element to fill the slot??!

The system supports unlimited slots, so there is no actual list of slots to compare against.

Here is my code so far:

```
$currentunits = array("001", "003", "004", "006");
$currentunits = array_diff($currentunits, range("001", "999"));
echo "<pre>";
print_r($currentunits);
```

Thanks in advance, and I hope I have not confused you!

Comment: You could `array_diff` with an array of all the slots.

Comment: I have tried looping through it and adding on numbers if they arent in the original list, but it didn't work. Then I got confused and decided to ask people who are more likely to know!

Comment: are you saying that slots in array `1,2,3,4` and you wanna detect from these slots which one in ASC or DSC is free `FIRST`??

Comment: You should post the code that is not working.

Comment: @softgenic Yes, basically. I also want a response of "5" if I input an array "1", "2", "3", "4", "6".

Comment: u meant input should get saved in fifth slot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that your **001** is the string `"001"` and not the number `1` (etc):

```
function findNextSlot($array) {
    $counter = +$array[0];
    foreach ($array as $current) {
        if (sprintf("%03d", $counter) != $current) {
            return sprintf("%03d", $counter);
        }
        $counter++;
    }
    return sprintf("%03d", $counter);
}
echo findNextSlot(array("001", "002", "003", "004", "005", "006")); // "007"
echo findNextSlot(array("001", "003", "004")); // "002"
```

Comment: This is the best solution that answers the question (using strings instead of integers)

Comment: @Leigh It does, if the OP had used integers like in your answer, all he /she would have to do is switch the arguments of `array_diff`. However, the OP's solution failed because the used slots were given as strings and `range` returns an array filled with integers.

Comment: @jeroen This answer has been edited like 5-6x already, mooting my comment ;)

Comment: @leigh: 5-6x? this is called _exaggeration_ :)

Comment: Yes, I agree. I have now switched to this one!

Answer (score 1):

If the arrays aren't huge, I'd probably detect the smallest and largest elements of the array, create an array that contains the full range, then compare this to the original.

```
$array = [3,1,4];


sort($array);

$min = $array[0];
$max = end($array);

$comparison = range($min, $max);

$diff = array_diff($comparison, $array);

if ($diff) {
    var_dump(current($diff));
}
else {
    var_dump(count($array) + 1);
}
```

Result

```
int(2)
```

Example:
http://codepad.viper-7.com/EIjI3I

Comment: Well, I used range($min, "999") and skipped the whole IF statement bit, but otherwise this is perfect! Thanks!

Comment: Well I didn't know there was an upper range, and the `if` is needed for when there is no difference, you probably want another if for if the array is full then.